# Seeeduino TFT and RPi?

Tags: gpio, screen

I have a spare [2.8" TFT Touchscreen from Seeeduino](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/2.8%27%27_TFT_Touch_Shield_V1.0) and I've been thinking about attaching a screen onto a RPi. However, I am not very familiar with hardware/electronics.

My screen uses 8 data lines + 4 not-quite-SPI lines. However, other examples never have 8 wires connected to 8 GPIO pins, such as [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=47040). [This one](http://marks-space.com/2013/05/27/raspberry-pi-with-a-3-2-tft-with-touch-control-part-2/) is just way over my head, and I dont have the parts, and I dont want to buy them.

Will this work? If so, how should the screen be wired? Can I use the `notro / fbtft` library for the software part of this?

Comment: Touch won't work because it's analog. But the display should be possible. Though you might have to bit-bang the data to the display. Not sure what protocol it uses, but you could just 'translate' the arduino code from tft.cpp. Note that you can't use it as a screen to display the output of the GPU. But you could use it to display status info. (But it would probably not be very easy)

Comment: @Gerben Interesting. I forgot to mention I only really care about video. I don't need the touch part of the screen. But since it won't get video from the gpu, darn

Comment: I don't think you could even get the framerate need for video. So, too bad :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is "no", you won't be able to use your 2.7" touchscreen display with Raspberry Pi.

you need an SPI-enabled screen to be able to connect it to the Raspberry Pi, otherwise there's just not enough data lines to send data back and forth and there are no ADC converters on RasPi to convert your touch position data, unless you want to get your hands dirty soldering away a breakout/conversion board, that might be quite an exercise in electronics.